# Accessing result of inserted document with Node JS and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this code:

```
var newresult = ""

oneDoc = { "adClientID": *randomID*, "adClientName": "abc", "adClientNameUPC": "ABC" }
newdoc.push(oneDoc)

await AdClient.create(newdoc, (err, result) => {
    console.log(result)
    console.log(result.adClientID)
    newresult = result
})
console.log(newresult)
```

Now I need to access the values that have been added to the collection.

With this code, the line that prints "result" works fine and print the following:

```
{
adClientID: 'da7d3d78-b873-4cdd-ae85-3726d3cbd8a7',
adClientName: 'abc',
adClientNameUPC: 'ABC',
_id: '5f6e4582a790764cab84f586',
__v: 0
}
```

But the line that prints `result.adClientID` returns undefined and the line that prints `newresult` returns an empty string.

What am I missing that prevent me to access specific data that was added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think your `await` is not actually awaiting anything. Mongoose says that this function can return a Promise (which can be awaited) or undefined.

`Returns undefined if used with callback or a Promise otherwise.`

I would recommend against mixing styles of asynchronous programming anyways.

I'm not too familiar with `.create` specifically because we usually use upserts, but here is how I would write it:

```
const updated = await AdModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { adClientID: oneDoc.adClientID },
  { $set: { ...oneDoc } },
  { new: true, upsert: true, ...options },
}).lean();

console.log(updated);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not realize I was mixing styles. Guess I have to review my lessons concerning promises. And, unfortunately, I can't use a function that does update as if a document with the same adClientName exist it must not be modified. So I will still have to  use create but make it work as a promise.